# Can I set list item user permissions for the username entered in item's field?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

## SOLVED:

I was able to add permissions for the user specified in the item Name field following these steps:

1. From within the **Impersonation Step**, add a **Add List Item Permissions** action.
2. Click **these permissions** link and then click the **Add** button.
3. In the **Add Permissions** dialogue box, click the **Choose** button.
4. Click the **Workflow Lookup for a User** from the user list and click **Add**.
5. In the **Lookup for Person or Group** dialogue box, set the **Data source** value to **Current Item**.
6. Set the **Field from source** field to the field that contains the user and click **OK** in the dialogue boxes to complete them.
7. Last thing you need to do is click the **this list** link in the action and select **Current Item**.

---

I have a simple SharePoint list with 3 fields: Title, Name, Idea. Using SharePoint Designer 2013 and implementing a 2010 workflow, I am able to strip the permissions of items as they are added to the list.

My question is this: is there a way to add permissions for a user that's specified in the Name field? So if John creates and item and enters "Sam" in the Name field, then Sam will receive unique permissions.

Thanks for the help. This would be relatively simple using Nintex :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom workflow activity to grant permissions to specific user on listitem. 
There are lot of activities available for sharepoint designer to grant permissions.

You can check:

https://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grant%20Permission%20on%20Item